# Handling server JAR in maven

Tags: jar, maven, m2eclipse, nexus

[image]

There are some server jars in my project which i want to migrate to maven ..

I don't have any idea how can i have dependencies attached to these jars.. there are almost 24 jars.. So how can add them to the project scope

Comment: what do you mean by server jars? Are they required at compilation time or at runtime or both?

Comment: they are required at both compile time and run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you can take depends on whether you have access to the sources of those 'server' jars or not. If you do, then nothing prevents you from creating one/more Maven projects, packaging these and deploying them in your Maven repository.

If you don't have access to the sources and these aren't already available in official Maven repositories, then all you can do is put those in your Maven repository by using maven install:

> Often times you will have 3rd party JARs that you need to put in your local repository for use in your builds. The JARs must be placed in the local repository in the correct place in order for it to be correctly picked up by Maven. To make this easier, and less error prone, we have provide a goal in the install plug-in which should make this relatively painless.

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`

Once done for all of these jars, just add dependencies to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you add the server jars in your POM, instead I just use the API jar

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The advantage is you are conforming to a portable standard.  M2E will compile things correctly and it will still run your application correctly when deployed to the runtime provided it supports the API.

If you want to explicitly see it you can add the runtime by going to the project preferences then going to Targetted Runtimes.  You only need to do it on the EAR it will do the included projects in the EAR for you.  The advantage of adding the targetted runtime is Eclipse may do extra validation specific for your server.